# Domain question in Reference to Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question states to Find the function f(f(x))

f(x)= 1/x

I set up the problem so, (1)/1/x.

I got (1x)/1 or I just x.

Furthermore, the problem ask one to find the domain. The answer in the book says that the domain is x not equal to 0.

How can than be? Should it not be all real numbers?

Please explain if you will.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with $0$ is that $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, so you can't evaluate $f(\frac{1}{x})$ at $x=0$. Therefore the domain will be all of the real numbers, except for $0$. As long as $x\neq0$, it will be true that $f(f(x))=x$.

Comment: But the answer is f[f(x)] = x, how is it that the domain can not be 0? Better yet. Why is there a restriction when it comes to 0?

Comment: You can get some funny contradictions if you let $f[f(x)]$ be defined at $0$. 

For example: assume that it has a value; $\frac{1}{1/x}=c$. Multiply both sides by $1/x$, then $1=\frac{c}{x}$. If you take the limit $x\to0$ you'll either get $1=+\infty$ or $1=-\infty$, unless you set $c=0$. In the special case that $c=0$, you'll get $1=0$. No matter how you look at it, you'll always end up with a funny contradiction, so $\frac{1}{1/x}$ has to be undefined at $x=0$.